# Is there a site that shows which grammar is used in the text?

Tags: grammar

Sometimes I don't know how to find a rule of grammar that explains to me why some text is written like that.

Do you know are there any sites that allow knowing what grammar is used in the text that I copied?

For example, I copied:

> I've read a book.

And the site says me:

I'**ve read** - Present Perfect

**a** book - article

Comment: Stanford has a [lex parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)...